# Losing connection in several different multiplayer games

Tags: internet-connection, connection, gaming

I'm having a connection problems with several multi-player games. It always happen during loading screens before the match, and I'm having problems identifying what could be the potential problem.

I'll list some games and what's happening:

- **League of Legends**: I'm able to chat and click start the match. Before the big loading screen would appear I get black screen. After a while I get a message that connection failed and I should check my firewall. Once (in about 30 tries) I got passed that message by clicking retry and got in game but kept loosing connection (get a small window saying "attempting to reconnect").
- **Team Fortress 2**: I'm able to start the tutorial (which is local I believe) and I can see the list of servers available. Once I select I server and loading starts it freezes on "Loading resources..." for a few minutes and then time-outs.
- **Gotham City Impostors**: Pretty much the same as above. First mission (tutorial) works, I get matched with other people, and then get stuck on pre-match loading until time out.
- **Dota2**: it freezes on loading pre-match or when I select a reply to watch. No time out it just stays there.

Other possible clues:

- I also have Diablo3 and Startcraft2 and both those games work perfectly in multi-player.
- My firewall is disabled.
- My router is probably fine, I tested LoL on a different computer in my house (same network) it works great.
- I'm using 32Mb/s cable internet

Any ideas what could cause such a behavior? I'm asking here because it seems to me that some software might lock a common port or a protocol is not working or something...

(I'm not sure this is the right place to ask, if not please let me know where can I place this question)

Comment: Which router do you use?

Comment: It's TP-LINK - Model No. TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND

Comment: Have you tried swapping the cst5e cables between the working system and the not working system to see if it's a cable issue.

Answer (score 0):

While your router might be fine, it is possible that the required ports are forwarded to another computer, when you want to play. Typically, the one on which you tested League of Legends, with success.

You should check the current port forwarding configuration on your router ([this site might help](http://portforward.com)). Check if there is not a computer set as DMZ, as well (to which everything would be forwarded by default).

---

Diablo 3 and Starcraft 2, from what I remember, both use [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) to setup their port forwarding, so that would explain why those two are working.

*Edit*: Nevermind, LoL should use UPnP as well, so it is most likely not your problem.

Comment: DMZ is disabled and nothing is set in the Virtual Servers or Port Triggering